# Github build and deploy action failed

Tags: reactjs, github, github-actions

I am working on an inherited ReactJS project and I have not touched the github actions. I've successfully deployed multiple commits without any issue, but today I received an error from the Github action and I'm having a hard time working out the problem.

There are a number of warnings about depreciated libraries but I don't believe they are causing the issue - they've always been there and I am not in a rush to change as there may be other unintended consequences.

I haven't updated anything in the project other than some source code.

Here is the log. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /github/workspace/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /opt/nodejs/16.18.0/bin/node /github/workspace/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/opt/nodejs/16.18.0/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/github/workspace/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.18.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/github/workspace/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/github/workspace/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/github/workspace/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /github/workspace/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /github/workspace/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /github/workspace/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:202:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/github/workspace/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/github/workspace/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/github/workspace/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /github/workspace/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /github/workspace/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /github/workspace/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:202:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python /opt/python/latest/bin/python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /opt/python/latest/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:402:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-1022-azure
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/opt/nodejs/16.18.0/bin/node" "/github/workspace/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /github/workspace/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.18.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /github/home/.npm/_logs/2022-11-09T02_26_49_887Z-debug-0.log
```

I've omitted the original warnings above these errors as I don't appear to be able to paste the whole amount in.

Comment: Did you find anything, getting this today too?

Comment: @JussiPalo I'm not entirely sure _why_, but I discovered the nodejs and npm version in the github action build were different to previous iterations. I set the engine values in package.json and that forced it to use the right version I needed. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hi discovered the node version and NPM versions in the GitHub action build were different to previous commits. I don't know what forced it to change the version (nothing in my code), but I did discover I hadn't set the engine values in the package.json.

I added the following to restore the previous versions:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.19.1",
    "npm": "6.14.16"
  },
```

This forced it to pick up the correct versions and deployed successfully.

Hope this helps someone.